Strange button(s) on desktop when working on Word
After some time working in Word I am getting this strange button or even two


It's not clear at all what they do, where they come from. But if I quit Word, they are disappearing. I don't have any plugins/addons installed as far as I know. It appears even if I minimize all windows, on desktop. Clicking on it brings Word menu only (not the window itself). What this might be and how to get rid of it?
Update - a small video on how this button behaves.

Update2 - the UI element appears to be from styles


It’s definately a Word issue. I would be tempted to delete all the ms word settings files, including the normal.dot template. Failing that I would completely uninstall word/office and reinstall.
